# JS: GetElementsByName from within form

Tags: javascript

im trying to get an element by name in my form, but for some reason im getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: frm.getElementsByName is not a function

Here is my code:

```
function doc(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

function switchFields() {
    var e = doc("slcSubmit");
    var sel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var frm = doc("frmSendmessage");

    var messageFields = [frm.getElementsByName("name"),frm.getElementsByName("email")]; //List of objects

    //Give each object a new class
    for (var i=0;i<messageFields.length;i++) {
        messageFields[i].class = "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getElementsByName` is not a function that can be applied to any node ([only to `document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)).

I think what you are looking for is `frm.querySelector('[name="TheName"]')`

Comment: getElementsByName is a function. See the link in my answer

Comment: @AmmarCSE I added your link, thanks for posting it and correcting me. I didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a substitute for getElementsByName that does not require Jquery, here is a function that you can use.

```
    //g is the dom element, cl is the value for the name attribute
        function getElementsByName(g, cl) {
            var e = [], b = g.childNodes, a, b, f, k;
            for (a = 0; a <= b.length - 1; a += 1) {
                if (b[a].getAttribute) {
                    if (cl == b[a].getAttribute("name")) {
                        e.push(b[a])
                    }
                }
                f = getElementsByName(b[a], cl);
                for (k = 0; k <= f - 1; k++) {
                    e.push(f[k])
                }
            }
            return e
        }
```